# Is there a simple way (one liner) to add an extra properties to the json output without having to write my own Json.writes

Tags: json, scala, playframework

```
import play.api.libs.json.JsonConfiguration.Aux
import play.api.libs.json._

case class EmailStats(id: Int, providerId: String, stats: Option[String])

case class Email(id: Int = 0, createdAt: Option[String], updatedAt: Option[String]) {

  implicit val config: Aux[Json.MacroOptions] = JsonConfiguration(SnakeCase)
  implicit def format: OFormat[Email] = Json.using[Json.WithDefaultValues].format[Email]
  implicit val writes: OWrites[Email] = Json.writes[Email]
  implicit val reads:  Reads[Email]   = Json.reads[Email]

  private var emailStats: Seq[EmailStats] = Seq[EmailStats]()

  def getEmailStats(): Seq[EmailStats] = emailStats
}
```

Output Serialization:

```
{"id": 0, "created_at": "01/08/2020 00:00:12","created_at": "01/09/2020 01:56:05"}
```

Is there a way to add an extra property or method to the writes so that it renders the extra JSON?

```
{"id": 0, "created_at": "01/08/2020 00:00:12","created_at": "01/09/2020 01:56:05", "email_stats": [...]}
```

I don't want to do the following:

```
implicit val writes: Writes[Email] = (email: Email) => Json.obj(
  "id" -> email.id,
  "created_at" -> email.createdAt,
  "updated_at" -> email.updatedAt
  "email_stats" -> email.getEmailStats.map(stat=>Json.toJson(stat))
)
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```scala
implicit val emailFormat: OFormat[Email] = {
  val f = Json.using[Json.WithDefaultValues].format[Email]

  OFormat(f, email => {
    f.writes(email) + ("email_stats" -> Json.toJson(email.getEmailStats))
  }
}
```

BTW, usually the implicits are added to the companion object instead of to the case class itself.

Comment: Ah, you’re totally correct, I didn’t paste the full code. This code actually lives in object Email {}. I knew there had to be a similar way. Much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution if you can adjust the *Case Classes*:

```
import play.api.libs.json._

  case class EmailStats(id: Int, providerId: String, stats: Option[String] = None)
  object EmailStats {
    implicit def format: OFormat[EmailStats] = Json.using[Json.WithDefaultValues].format[EmailStats]

  }
  case class Email(id: Int = 0, createdAt: Option[String], updatedAt: Option[String], emailStats: Seq[EmailStats]) {
  }
  object Email {
    implicit def format: OFormat[Email] = Json.using[Json.WithDefaultValues].format[Email]

  }
```

1. Adjust the Constructors (added `emailStats`).
2. Add the Formatters in the *Companion Objects*.

Here the example:

```
val jsonStr = """{"id": 0, "createdAt": "01/08/2020 00:00:12","updatedAt": "01/09/2020 01:56:05", "emailStats": [{"id": 3, "providerId": "provider" }]}
              |""".stripMargin

Json.parse(jsonStr).validate[Email] // -> JsSuccess(Email(0,Some(01/08/2020 00:00:12),Some(01/09/2020 01:56:05),List(EmailStats(3,provider,None))),)
```

Let me know if you need more explanation.

Be aware that I changed some of the properties to `CamelCase`, to simplify the example.

Comment: Ya i already know of this solution. This solution won’t work with the problem I trying to solve.